# Webpack compile export from ts file into nothing

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webpack, export

There is only one line in my index.ts file.

```
export * from "./foo"
```

There is only one line in foo.ts file too.

```
export const foo = ()=> 'bar'
```

I'm only using default config from "npx webpack-cli init".
Only "mode" and "output" are edited.

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output:{
    filename:'index.js'
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.ProgressPlugin()],

  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
      exclude: [/node_modules/],
      options:{
        transpileOnly: true
      }
    }]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  },

  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],

    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          priority: -10,
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
        }
      },

      chunks: 'async',
      minChunks: 1,
      minSize: 30000,
      name: false
    }
  },
  target:"web"
}
```

And here is my tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "npm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@webpack-cli/init": "^1.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.12",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.10.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

With these when I run build

```
"build": "webpack"
```

I got an empty index.js in "dist/index.js".
What am I missing?

Comment: When I compile with typescript "tsc" it's ok

Comment: Can you also share your `package.json`?

Comment: I edited the question to include package.json

Comment: @tmhao2005 hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here all about to remove unused export of `webpack`. Keep in mind that `webpack` is able to do this unless the input code passed to it must be `esm` style as same as you've done by configured `module: "es6"`.

In case of exporting as library, you might have to tell webpack to build as library by specifying target or even could add a name:

`webpack.config.js`

```json
{
  output: {
    library: "yourLibName",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    filename: "index.js"
  },
}
```

Comment: My code will be used in browser environment.
I think commonjs is for node environment.
Will there be any problem if I change to "commonjs"?

Comment: Nope. `commonjs` will be passed to `webpack` then it will actually be converted to code which supports to run on browser

Comment: Thank you. With commonjs, index.js file is no longer empty. But I can't import from it in browser environment.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to create npm package. My idea is to export everything in main file(index.js). Right now I'm only getting an empty object when importing from the main file.

Comment: Ah I see. I dropped another hint for you

Comment: Thanks man. it's working as I intended now. Can you plz explain or drop me a link where I can read why this works?

Comment: You can go to `webpack` official website to read output option